# List all files and the default path for a java application

Tags: java, file-io, io

Sometimes we have problems when loading a file on a Java standard a application because we get lost to find the default path, specialy using a build tool or IDEs like Eclipse or Netbeans.
How can we list the default path for the application and the files in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you don't say what "default path" you are talking about.

- If you want to know the command execution path, it is in the PATH environment variable.
- If you want the build or execution classpath, the "default" and the way to find out what it is both depend on the tool that you are using.
- If you want the current directory, then see Rafael's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use the code above on your application. It will print the current path (".") and list all files on it.

```
File currentFolder = new File(".");
File[] listOfFiles = currentFolder.listFiles();
System.out.printf("Current path: %s\n", currentFolder.getAbsolutePath());
  for (File file : listOfFiles) {
    // Test if it is no
    if (file.isFile()) {
      System.out.println(file.getName());
    }
  }
```